# Why subclass's instance declared as parent type doesn't have its additional members in Scala?

Tags: scala, oop

```
class Parent {
  def getName = "parent"
}

class Child extends Parent {
  override def getName = "child"
  def getAge = "1"
}
```

```
val oneChild : Parent = new Child()
oneChild.getName = "child"
oneChild.getAge  // does not exists
```

The variable type is `Parent`, but the actual object is `Child`.

Precisely, does the getAge method not exist or is it inaccessible?

Comment: I have experience with C++, never really came to me this is about compiling. Now it makes more sense now. Thank you

Comment: If you are playing in a REPL and you need to access `getAge` for whatever reasons, you can do a dirty cast `oneChild.asInstanceOf[Child].getAge` just never do this on real code.

Comment: I will try it out and remember this. I appreciate it ^^ I think I get this now, the compiler read line oneChild.getAge and discovered Parent type does not have this member, threw the error. regardless of what type the object exactly is

Comment: Almost correct, _"regardless of what type the object exactly is"_ the correct phrase would be _"regardless of what **class** the object exactly is"_ - [**classes** and **types** are not the same](https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html), and the compiler only cares about **types**, since in the general sense it can't know what is the real class of a value; and it shouldn't, since that would break parametricity.

Comment: ok, That is super helpful, thank you for the explanation and the link <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Luis's comments, imagine that instead of writing

```
val oneChild: Parent = new Child()
val name: String = oneChild.getName
val age: String = oneChild.getAge  // Doesn't compile
// Do something with name and age
```

we had the semantically identical (you can always translate a block of code into something with more or less this form)

```
def line2(parent: Parent): String =
  parent.getName

def line3[T](parent: Parent, state: T): (String, T) =
  parent.getAge -> state  // doesn't compile

def doSomething(state: (String, String)): Unit = ???

val oneChild = new Child()  // Note the removed type ascription...

doSomething(line3(oneChild, line2(oneChild))
```

We can obviously use `oneChild` as a `Parent`, because `Child extends Parent`, and `Parent` has a `getName` method, so `line2` is fine.  But when compiling `line3`, all we & the compiler know is that it's a `Parent` (and there's no reason a caller couldn't pass in a `Parent` that's not a `Child`), and not all `Parent`s have a `getAge` method.  So even if the compiler realized in the 3-line snippet above that `oneChild` is always going to be an instance of `Child`, the requirement that the code be able to be rewritten as the second snippet means the compiler has to reject an attempt to call `getAge` on a `Parent`.

When you ascribe a supertype to a value (as in `oneChild: Parent = new Child()` or `new Child(): Parent` or `new Child().asInstanceOf[Parent]`), you're basically telling the compiler: "this is a `Child`, but forget that it's anything but a `Parent`".

As far as I can tell, C++ enforces a similar restriction (apologies for probably the most atrocious C++ ever posted to SO, I haven't written C++ in some 20 years):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent {
    public:
    virtual char* getName();
};

class Child : public Parent {
    public:
    virtual char* getAge() { return "12"; }

    char* getName() { return "child"; }
};

class App {
    void run() {
        Parent* p = new Child();
        cout << p->getName() << "\n";
        cout << p->getAge() << "\n";
    }
};
```

Gives the following compiler error (from G++):

> ‘class Parent’ has no member named ‘getAge’